# How to show that a nonlinear system of equations has a unique solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Consider the   system below of 13 equations with unknowns $\alpha, p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4$, each belonging to $[0,1]$. Could you help me to show that this system has a unique solution?
$$
\begin{aligned}
&q_1\Big[  (1-\alpha)^2 p_1 + \alpha^2 (1-p_1)\Big]=x_1\\
&q_1\Big[ \alpha(1-\alpha) p_1 +(1-\alpha) \alpha (1-p_1)\Big]=x_2\\
&q_1\Big[ \alpha^2 p_1 +(1-\alpha)^2   (1-p_1)\Big]=x_3\\
&q_2\Big[  (1-\alpha)^2 p_2 + \alpha^2 (1-p_2)\Big]=x_4\\
&q_2\Big[ \alpha(1-\alpha) p_2 +(1-\alpha) \alpha (1-p_2)\Big]=x_5\\
&q_2\Big[ \alpha^2 p_2 +(1-\alpha)^2   (1-p_2)\Big]=x_6\\
&q_3\Big[  (1-\alpha)^2 p_3 + \alpha^2 (1-p_3)\Big]=x_7\\
&q_3\Big[ \alpha(1-\alpha) p_3 +(1-\alpha) \alpha (1-p_3)\Big]=x_8\\
&q_3\Big[ \alpha^2 p_3 +(1-\alpha)^2   (1-p_3)\Big]=x_9\\
&q_4\Big[  (1-\alpha)^2 p_4 + \alpha^2 (1-p_4)\Big]=x_{10}\\
&q_4\Big[ \alpha(1-\alpha) p_4 +(1-\alpha) \alpha (1-p_4)\Big]=x_{11}\\
&q_4\Big[ \alpha^2 p_4 +(1-\alpha)^2   (1-p_4)\Big]=x_{12}\\
&q_1+q_2+q_3+q_4=1
\end{aligned}
$$

Also, each $x_j$ is a number in $(0,1)$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{12}x_j=1$

---

Some considerations:

(1) If needed to have one unique solution, we can restrict all the parameters to $(0,1)$ and $\alpha>1/2$.

(2) The left-hand side of the 12 equations exhibits some patterns. In fact, it can be more compactly written as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& q_i\Big[ \alpha^j(1-\alpha)^h p_i +(1-\alpha)^j \alpha^h (1-p_i)\Big]\\
& i\in \{1,2,3,4\},  (j,h)\in \{\{0,1,2\}^2: j+h=2\}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Can you get a different solution set for $\alpha = \frac{1}{4}$ and $\alpha = \frac{3}{4}$?

Comment: Yes, I do. Anyway, if needed, I can assume $\alpha>1/2$ (added to my question).